# Global Frame Quaternion vs Body Frame Quaternion

Tags: quaternions, gyroscope

I have angular rates from 3D IMU attached to the body of say a quadcopter. I want to update my quaternions (Expressed in the global frame) using these angular rates. From a lot of searches, I came to know that quaternion expressed in body frame is different from quaternion expressed in the global frame. So how to update a quaternion expressed in the global frame by using body frame angular rates given in rad/sec. please guide.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial problem. I think what you would need to do is first find an initial relationship between your gyroscope and the quaternions, then integrate the gyroscope to find the rotation, and apply that rotation to your global frame.

Two big issues: Your frame of reference is what's rotating, and you need to account for that; rotating 45 around X then 45 around Z (rotated) is different from going 45 around Z then 45 around X (rotated), which is different from going 45 around X and Z at the same time. The second issue is the dead reckoning issue, any drift from the gyroscope will build up over time.

There are plenty of small, low power IMU sensors that will put out quaternions, even referenced to magnetic North. I've used the BHI160 and BNO055, both from Bosch.

Comment: I think you didnt get the answer, i am also confused about global quaternion vs body frame quaternion. and how to update both using angular rates of gyro... If you get the answer, please share